# C++ cout not printing all args

Tags: c++, cout

I have the following code to print out a Car object. All the fields are publicly accessible.

```
void print_cars_array(Car cars[]) {
/**
 * Prints all cars in the given car array.
 */
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CARS; i++) {
      std::cout << "Car #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
      std::cout << cars[i].year << ' ' << cars[i].color << ' ' << cars[i].make << ' ' << cars[i].model << std::endl;
  }
}
```

However, this gives me the following output:

```
Car #1
 Subaru Outback
Car #2
 Toyota Corolla
...
```

At first I thought the first two fields were messed up, but modifying the loop to this:

```
void print_cars_array(Car cars[]) {
/**
 * Prints all cars in the given car array.
 */
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CARS; i++) {
      std::cout << "Car #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
      std::cout << cars[i].year << std::endl;
      std::cout << cars[i].color << std::endl;
      std::cout << cars[i].year << ' ' << cars[i].color << ' ' << cars[i].make << ' ' << cars[i].model << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Produces the following:

```
Car #1
2016
green
 Subaru Outback
Car #2
2006
white
 Toyota Corolla
```

Am I missing something as to why those won't print? All fields except `year` are strings, and `year` is an int.

Comment: Sounds like `make` has a carriage return in it.  You should inspect the string with your debugger to check.

Comment: and that extra space at the front looks odd too. Yes, you have some non alphanumeric chars in your strings

Answer (score 1):

Try `to_string()` as the issue could be with int and string type concatenation

Ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/